# File only can be accessed if it's present in target folder

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

I'm facing such problem: during test run I'm generating yaml file which appearing in resource folder, but then when I'm trying to reach that resource with

```java
SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("somefile.yaml");
```

I'm getting null.
And after first run of the program file is appearing in a target folder, and that code above is not giving me NPE if file is in target.
So how to get rid of NPE when file is not in target but only in resource folder?

Comment: it should be under the resource folder with the same path as the `SomeClass` is for example is the some class is under `src/main/java/com/myapp/SomeClass` then the yaml file should be under `src/main/resources/com/myapp/`

Comment: @KarimTawfik , thanks, yes, it is there, but still NPE...Im only thinking maybe its because file is created during run, and not existed before? But should it  be the problem?

Comment: not 100%, but it could be the case, you can try it with a static file and make sure whether you are able to read it or not, if you can read it, then the created file on the fly is not picked by the JVM resources.

Comment: Ok, I figured out solution, kind a workaround but sometimes its enough right?
So if java wants the file in target folder I just copied it during execution

' FileUtils.
                    copyFileToDirectory(file,
                            new File("C\target\\classes"));'